# Injectivity of a Function

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Sorry for confusion.

I am in the process of solving a functional equation, I need to show injectivity. (By the way i know that it is injective, I'm trying to prove it to myself).

Putting $f(x)=f(y)$ yields $x(f(x)-1)=y(f(x)-1)$. To obtain $x=y$, and thus show injectivity, I need to divide by $f(x)-1$, which is only allowed if $f(x)\not=1$. Is the function injective?

Comment: I guess you meant to ask something else. There are many non-injective functions with $f(x) \neq 1$.

Comment: Now that starts to make more sense, what is the domain, range of $f$? What is $y$?

Comment: $f:R \rightarrow R$ and $x,y$ are real numbers

Comment: Did you somehow forget to write a part of the question?

Comment: No, but the initial way I wrote it was misleading and confusing. I've done my best to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on $f$. It is certainly true for the obviously not injective $f$: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\in\Bbb Q\\1&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$